# Bring last activity to front again

Tags: android

I have an android application which consists of three activities:

1. `LoginActivity`
2. `MapActivity`
3. `RegisterActivty`

The Application starts with the `LoginActivity` and from there the app can open the `RegisterActivty` or the `MapActivty`.

Now suppose that from the `LoginActivity` the app opens the `RegisterActivity` and the user exits the app by pressing the `home button`.

Then, when I start my app again, it opens the `RegisterActivty`, that's good; but when I go from the `LoginActicty` to the `MapActivity` and do the same, I don't get the `MapActivty` - instead the app goes back to launching the `LoginActivity`.

**How do I make my app remember what Activity was open last time it was used?**

Comment: how do you start MapActivity?

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MapActivity.class));

Comment: no i am not using finish atall

Comment: check android manifest, for mapactivity if it has noHistory="true"

Comment: thanks all i got solution it was problem in androidmainfiest.xml 
for MapActivty android:noHistory ="true" was set

Comment: LoginActivity is your app start point?

Comment: What activity is start when you start app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `android:noHistory="true"` from android manifest for the map activity.